# Resampling Data by daily mean

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, average, resampling

[image]

I have an excel file with timeseries data of discharge for various locations, but some years are missing in between, for example, I could have 1983-1985 for a station, then 1990 again, and so on. I intend to create a model, but the input required is an average daily discharge, i.e. for a station with two years or more of data, I need to create a pandas with average rainfall values for each day. To be more specific, if I have data from 1983, 1984, and 1985. I'll have one pandas with average rainfall from January 1st to December 31st.

I tried this simple formula: df avg = df.resample('D').mean(), but it did not return the desired result.

For example if I have:
Date        |  Discharge
01/01/1990  |  15
till
31/12/2015  |  20 (as shown in first image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XuuY.png))

But in between, there could be missing days, months or even years, I now need just one pandas with 366 rows (to accomodate leap years) now that will take the average of each day for all the available years and return it, e.g.
Date    |  Avg Discharge
Jan 1st |   16           As shown in the second image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvca.png)

Comment: Please provide some input data (or some code that generates dummy data?), your current problem (why did `resample("D").mean()` not give the desired result?), and the expected output

Comment: Hi, I just added it to my question, thanks